# How to generate a self-signed certificate using only JDK supported classes?

Tags: java, x509certificate

I have a program in Java which currently uses private JDK classes (`CertAndKeyGen` and `X500Name`) to generate self-signed X.509 certificates.
There are too many problems with this approach:

- the internal package(s) keep changing:

  - "sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen",          // Oracle/Sun/OpenJDK 6,7
  - "sun.security.tools.keytool.CertAndKeyGen", // Oracle/Sun/OpenJDK 8
  - "com.ibm.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen",      // IBM SDK 7
  - "com.ibm.security.tools.CertAndKeyGen"      // IBM SDK 8
  - Apparently a JDK 7 update (u111?) recently changed the package listed above
- Java 9 will hide these classes

I would like to convert this code to use standard, supported JDK classes.

I have looked at using the ill-named `CertificateFactory.generateCertificate()` methods, but no luck: they cannot generate any certificate, they are just able to load an existing one.

Does anybody know a standard JDK API that can generate a self-signed certificate?

This is as far as I could go:

```
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
generator.initialize(2048, SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA"));
KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey privatekey = keyPair.getPrivate();

X500Principal principal = new X500Principal(dn);

CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
// How to generate the self-signed certificate from there?
// certFactory.generate(inputStream) // only able to load an existing certificate
```

Note:

- We do not want to introduce a dependency on bouncy-castle if at all possible

  - I already know of `X509V3CertificateGenerator`
- We do not want either to invoke `keytool` via a `ProcessBuilder` :)

Comment: I noticed this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410695/how-to-programmatically-generate-a-self-signed-certificate but it attracted answers that focused on the code, but not the question.

Comment: Of course it is only now that I find a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220377/alternative-to-certandkeygen-for-self-signed-certificate-generation-in-java?rq=1

Comment: I have submitted a RFE for Java to Oracle. Let's see when I'll get an answer.

Comment: The bouncycastle library has an excellent class, [X509v3CertificateBuilder](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cert/X509v3CertificateBuilder.html) that does what you want. Java 8 does not have any built-in support for this. You can write your own code, but then you'd just be duplicating the open source bouncycastle code. So why not bouncycastle?

Comment: I am not the one who decides :) It looks like we'll have no choice.

Comment: I can not believe that there is no Java Standard Support for this?! Unfortunatly we can not vote for bugs anymore: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8058778

Comment: @JnRouvignac - have you made any progress since then with non-BC solutions? :-)

Comment: We wrote our own certificate builder: https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENDJ-6258

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, then I guess it does not exist.

The RFE I submitted to the JDK has been accepted and there is now an official bug for it: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8165481

Comment: It was flagged as a duplicate. The request is still open since 2014 though: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8058778