# How to generate self-signed certificate in Java with JDK17

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, java-17, openjdk-17

tl,dr; **Is there a native Java17 solution to generate self-signed certificate, either via standard library (very unlikely) or some slim, lightweight library?**

There is a similar question ([Access `sun.security.x509` in JDK 11 without modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61149455/access-sun-security-x509-in-jdk-11-without-modules), asked by me) because starting with JDK11 access to internal JDK packages has been limited thus it's not possible to use classes from `sun.security.x509`. Up until JDK17 there was possibility to circumvent it with certain compiler configuration to flag to open those packages. This changed with JDK17, which removed that option.

From what I was able to gather current solutions are either:

1. BouncyCastle - but it's a hefty 5MB swiss-knife security library thus using it only for generating certificate seems somewhat wasteful.
2. calling directly `keytool` java tool, but this has two downsides: calling external tool is slower and it requires creating keystore file.

Currently (2) seems more convenient in my usecase but I would love to find third option - native, lightweight solution.

EDIT: there is OpenJDK issue: [JDK-8058778: New APIs for creating certificates and certificate requests](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8058778) and I hope one day it would be implemented...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, basic and crude implementation relying on `keytool` is available here: [KeytoolCertificateGenerator.java](https://github.com/tigase/tigase-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/tigase/cert/KeytoolCertificateGenerator.java)

Comment: Does it allow generating only self-signed certificates?

Comment: Yes, it only allows self-signed as for proper certificate you need to contact proper CA. In that case you could use [acme4j](https://github.com/shred/acme4j) to obtain Let's Encrypt certificate, but that is slightly different use-case.

Comment: Actually, I don't need real CA, I did some certificate chain with "CA" for test purposes with bouncy castle, but I am looking for another way to create certificates, I found your questions and for now, I see only keytool via processbuilder and sun.security with --exports option, probably you found a better way to create certificates?

Comment: No, we ended up with `keytool` option for now, there is OpenJDK issue: [JDK-8058778: New APIs for creating certificates and certificate requests](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8058778) and I hope one day it would be implemented but for now we wanted to adopt never Java versions and `keytool` was the best middleground for us (least dependencies, lower impact on resources and relatively compatible). I think it should be possible to use own CA to sign certificate from CSR using `keytool` but that was out of scope for us.