# How to generate X.509 certificates in Java 11 without using bouncycastle?

Tags: x509certificate, java-11, x509

There is bouncycastle but it is third party. I am looking for something that comes with java11 and deprecated in it.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;

public class X509CertificateGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048); 
            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();


            X509Certificate certificate = generateCertificate(keyPair);


            System.out.println(certificate.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static X509Certificate generateCertificate(KeyPair keyPair) throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {
        try {

            X509V3CertificateGenerator certGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();


            certGenerator.setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            certGenerator.setSubjectDN(new X500Principal("CN=Test Certificate"));
            certGenerator.setIssuerDN(new X500Principal("CN=Test Certificate"));
            certGenerator.setNotBefore(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // Yesterday
            certGenerator.setNotAfter(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // One year from now
            certGenerator.setPublicKey(keyPair.getPublic());
            certGenerator.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA256WithRSAEncryption");


            X509Certificate certificate = certGenerator.generate(keyPair.getPrivate());

            return certificate;
        } catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
            throw new CertificateException("Failed to generate certificate.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here `X509V3CertificateGenerator` is from bouncycastle. What is replacement for this? Or some other way to generate x509 certificates.

Comment: The `keytool` _program_ can create a selfsigned cert for a new keypair or a CA-issued one (from a CSR given a CA cert&key), but it uses internal classes not easily accessible in Java >= 9 and not at all in Java >= 17. Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615871/creating-an-x509-certificate-in-java-without-bouncycastle (for older) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71441994/how-to-generate-self-signed-certificate-in-java-with-jdk17 .